# Como iterar en un Query MYSQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Muy buenas, quisiera calcular el saldo con los movimientos que tiene un cliente determinado, tengo que ir sumando las cantidades que se encuentren en la columna Cantidad y restando la columna Cantidad_dev esto en cada línea.
Esta es la estructura de mi tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo la siguiente consulta que si me da el saldo, pero necesito que se muestre cada iteración.

```
SELECT c.Nombres, c.Apellido, m.fecha, m.Cantidad, m.Cantidad_dev, SUM(m.Cantidad-m.Cantidad_dev) AS saldo
FROM movimientos AS m
INNER JOIN clientes AS c ON m.Id_control=c.Id_cliente
```

Quiero un resultado aproximadamente como la siguiente tabla, donde el debe sería mi columna Cantidad, el Haber la columna Cantidad_dev.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desde ya gracias!!!

Comment: Has intentado algo?

Comment: Si, he actualizado la pregunta, puedes revisar?

Comment: Elimina la función de totales `SUM()` y podrás ver todos los registros de la tabla, en vez de tu totalización